# Automatically add all model fields to django rest serializer

Tags: django, rest, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

When i define a ModelSerializer the meta class can be used for defining fields which are to be serialized it automagically inherits all fields in the Model:

```
class ClientSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
```

I have to build a nested serializer (based on a SerializerMethodField). So i have to define the fields which to include:

```
class ClientSerializer(ModelSerializer)
     address = SerializerMethodField('get_client_addresses')

     class Meta:
          model = Client
          fields = ('address','name','city', <etc*>)

     def get_client_addresses(self, obj):
          addresses = Addresses.objects.all().filter(parent=obj)
          serializer = AddressSerializer(addresses, many=True,
                                         context={'request', self.context.get('request') })
          return serializer.data
```

**Question**: In this case i have to manually add *all* client-fields to the fields-tuple. I don't want to do that since it seems pretty repetatative and fault sensitive. How can i add a "plus-1" field (in this case address) to the default fields that are included when a ModelSerialzer is used???

note: this is a simplified example. I have models with 40+ fields and i have to use a SerializerMethodField for the nested models, since i have to pass the context data (user-info) to the serializer for field-level authentication i have implemented.

(update, address is a SerializerMethodField, got names mixed up)

Comment: any reason you're not using `Meta.exclude` instead of `Meta.fields` [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include)

Comment: As i understand it i need to add the "address" to the Meta.fields explicitly to include the field in the serializer (since it's a 'extra' field not part to the Client model, or don't i ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the `ModelSerializer` returns all model fields if `fields` argument is not defined in the `Meta`.
Similarly for normal `serializers.Serializer`, it will return all the fields defined in the serializer(except `read-only` fields).

You have to specify `fields` in your `Meta` class only if you want a subset of all the fields to be returned.

**(From the DRF docs)**

> If you only want a subset of the default fields to be used in a model
>   serializer, you can do so using `fields` or `exclude` options.

So just don't specify the `fields` argument in your `Meta` class and it should return all the fields.

Comment: Tnx. I was under the impression that fields that are not "defined in the model" but only in the serializer were not automatically included. It works if i remove the Meta.fields declaration

Comment: I can understand why this is confusing, the tutorial first introduces `ModelSerializer` with a `fields` attribute without explaining the reason (and as far as I can tell without actually needing it). Thus it looks like a standard requirement.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the list of fields from the model. It is reachable in `model._meta.fields`. At this point, you may add the field `address` if it's not part of your model.

Even better, with django 1.8, you can use model.get_fields. [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model)